# Does TRichEdit support Unicode?

Tags: delphi, unicode, delphi-xe2, rtf, richtext

I'm trying to write a wrapper class around `TRichEdit` that can encode and decode RTF to/from plaintext.

This is what I've written so far:

```
type
  TRTF = class
  private
    FRichEdit : TRichEdit;
    procedure SetText(const AText: string);
    function GetText: string;
    class function Convert(const AInput: string; AEncode: Boolean): string; inline; static;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    class function Decode(const AInput: string): string; static;
    class function Encode(const AInput: string): string; static;
  end;

constructor TRTF.Create;
begin
  FRichEdit := TRichEdit.CreateParented(HWND_MESSAGE);
end;

destructor TRTF.Destroy;
begin
  FRichEdit.Free;
  inherited;
end;

function TRTF.GetText: string;
var
  Stream: TStringStream;
begin
  if FRichEdit.PlainText then begin
    Stream := TStringStream.Create('', TEncoding.ANSI);
  end else begin
    Stream := TStringStream.Create('', TEncoding.ASCII);
  end;
  try
    FRichEdit.Lines.SaveToStream(Stream, Stream.Encoding);
    Result := Stream.DataString;
  finally
    Stream.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TRTF.SetText(const AText: string);
var
  Stream: TStringStream;
begin
  if FRichEdit.PlainText then begin
    Stream := TStringStream.Create(AText, TEncoding.ANSI);
  end else begin
    Stream := TStringStream.Create(AText, TEncoding.ASCII);
  end;
  try
    Stream.Seek(0, TSeekOrigin.soBeginning);
    FRichEdit.Lines.LoadFromStream(Stream);
  finally
    Stream.Free;
  end;
end;

class function TRTF.Convert(const AInput: string; AEncode: Boolean): string;
var
  RTF: TRTF;
begin
  RTF := TRTF.Create;
  try
    RTF.FRichEdit.PlainText := AEncode;
    RTF.SetText(AInput);
    RTF.FRichEdit.PlainText := not AEncode;
    Result := RTF.GetText;
  finally
    RTF.Free;
  end;
end;

class function TRTF.Encode(const AInput: string): string;
begin
  Result := Convert(AInput, True);
end;

class function TRTF.Decode(const AInput: string): string;
begin
  Result := Convert(AInput, False);
end;
```

This seems to be working reasonably well for everything that can be represented by the user default ANSI codepage.

It fails (converts them to `?`) for other characters though.

Is there an easy way to enable correct Unicode handling in my code?

I tried to use `TEncoding.Unicode` and `TEncoding.UTF8` as the encoding for the `TStringStream` when the `TRichEdit` is set to `PlainText := True`, but that doesn't work.

Comment: Slightly off-topic: Why aren't you inheriting from the `TRichEdit` instead?

Comment: @JerryDodge: Then it would become a control.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Well yes, that was my point. I was just wondering why it's not an inherited control.

Comment: @Jerry Because Jens wants a non visual class that will perform text processing to and from RTF.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Then Jens should not be using `TRichEdit` at all. Jens should be using a [Windowless RichEdit control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787613.aspx) instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau This API seems to be complicated to implement, is it worth the effort over using a `TRichEdit`?

Comment: Rob Kennedy has some wrapper units here: http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~rkennedy/windowless-rtf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are over-complicating this. There's no need to use the `PlainText` property at all. Leave it at its default setting of `True`. Then, to read/write RTF use `LoadFromStream` and `SaveToStream`. And to read/write plain text use the `Lines.Text` property.

This is about as simple as I can make it:

```
type
  TRTF = class
  strict private
    class function CreateRichEdit: TRichEdit; static;
  public
    class function Decode(const AInput: string): string; static;
    class function Encode(const AInput: string): string; static;
  end;

class function TRTF.CreateRichEdit: TRichEdit;
begin
  Result := TRichEdit.CreateParented(HWND_MESSAGE);
end;

class function TRTF.Encode(const AInput: string): string;
var
  RichEdit: TRichEdit;
  Stream: TStringStream;
begin
  RichEdit := CreateRichEdit;
  try
    RichEdit.Lines.Text := AInput;
    Stream := TStringStream.Create;
    try
      RichEdit.Lines.SaveToStream(Stream);
      Result := Stream.DataString;
    finally
      Stream.Free;
    end;
  finally
    RichEdit.Free;
  end;
end;

class function TRTF.Decode(const AInput: string): string;
var
  RichEdit: TRichEdit;
  Stream: TStringStream;
begin
  RichEdit := CreateRichEdit;
  try
    Stream := TStringStream.Create(AInput);
    try
      RichEdit.Lines.LoadFromStream(Stream);
      Result := RichEdit.Lines.Text;
    finally
      Stream.Free;
    end;
  finally
    RichEdit.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: As an aside, I'm not convinced by `TRichEdit.CreateParented(HWND_MESSAGE)`. When I've used that I find that it formatting can be mangled when emitting RTF. I'd use `TRichEdit.Create(nil)` and then assign the controls `ParentWindow` to `Application.Handle`.

Comment: So using `LoadFromStream` for Unicode plaintext doesn't work at all?

Comment: Regarding the Parent: What would you use in a console application?

Comment: @JensMühlenhoff LoadFromStream with Unicode plaintext is catered for by the code. To be honest I didn't try to understand where your code was going wrong. I just wrote my own version from scratch.

Comment: For a console application you'd probably want to create a hidden window. If you replicate what's done with Application.Handle that would do the job. But I suspect `HWND_MESSAGE` is not good. Again, I've not dug into this much. Rich text is really not my thing!

Comment: It is not correct to use a windowed `TRichEdit` for non-visual work. Microsoft has a completely separate API for non-visual RTF work: [Windowless RichEdit controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787613.aspx);

Comment: Thanks David. I had the same problem with TRichEdit characterset encoding, and this code solved the problem, while saving me a lot of time.